# Multiple entry points without common chunks or dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm making a chrome extension that hosts multiple applications (multiple devtools panels), each one independent. I need webpack to watch multiple entry points and produce multiple bundles, I don't need common chunks. I definitely do not want to use amd in the client side code [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31670677/4769440).

```
/appOne
    index.js
    /components
        /blah
        /foobar
/appTwo
    index.js
    /components
        ..etc
/appThree
    index.js
    /components
        ..etc.
/chrome     <- basically the "dist" folder
    /appOne
        index.html
        bundle.js
    /appTwo
        index.html
        bundle.js
    /appThree
        etc...
```

As per docs on multiple entries I've been doing:

```
{
    entry: {
        appOne: './appOne/index.js',
        appTwo: './appTwo/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'chrome', '[name]'),
        filename: 'bundle.js' //can be the same since they should be output in different folders
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Path variable [name] not implemented in this context: C:\Users\Admin\projects\crx\chrome\[name]
```

So I guess you cannot have the `[name]` variable in the `path` setting for multiple entries?

Comment: I think `[name]` needs to be in the filename rather than the path, i.e. `{path: path.join(__dirname, 'chrome'), filename: '[name].bundle.js'}`

Comment: Yes, but then how can I specify a dynamic path for each output? That is, I don't want all bundles to be in the same folder.

Comment: Oh wow you are right, i just did `[name]/bundle.js` instead, my god.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `[name]` in the filename field instead of path. Looking at the docs, [filename lists the `[name]` variable](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename) and [path does not](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path) (only showing `[hash]`).

You would use something like:

```
{
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'chrome'),
  filename: '[name]/bundle.js'
}
```

The documentation does not explicitly state the `filename` can have multiple path segments, it only says the `filename` must not be an *absolute* path.